# Opening a notification in new tab doesn't mark the notification as read

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

I often open notifications in a new tab and recently they don't go away when you click and open in the tab. So after opening and reading the comment, I need to click notification again to hide it and mark as read.

Comment: [Related request on initial feature announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384266)

Comment: Are you right clicking and selecting "Open link in new tab"? You can instead try using the middle mouse button and that should mark it as read.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat middle mouse buttons work but it don't focus on the tab, I prefer to use the Open link in the new tab. Old notifications were marking the page that I open as read not only through notifications. The same if you have a question and refresh the page and then read all comments and need to click on each individual notification to mark it as read. This is really bad UX.

Comment: @jcubic The "open link in new tab" option focuses the tab for you? That does not seem to happen for me... What if you try Ctrl + Shift + Click, that should do what you want I guess

Comment: I have observed this behaviour, but there are so many other ways to get the notification "read" marks out of sync that the whole thing would need an overhaul to be fixed.